# How to reformat an R data frame with multiple rows into one row

Tags: r, reshape

I have data frames like the following that I need to reformat into a single row, so that I can create a new data frame that's a collection of many of the simpler data frames, with one row in the new data frame representing all of the data of one of the simpler original data frames.

Here's a trivial example of the format of the original data frames:

```
> myDf = data.frame(Seconds=seq(0,1,.25), s1=seq(0,8,2), s2=seq(1,9,2))
> 
> myDf
  Seconds s1 s2
1    0.00  0  1
2    0.25  2  3
3    0.50  4  5
4    0.75  6  7
5    1.00  8  9
```

And below is what I want it to look like after being reformatted. Each column indicates rXsY, where "rX" indicates the row number of the original data frame, and "sY" indicates the "s1" or "s2" column of the original data frame. The "Seconds" column is omitted in the new data frame, as its information is implicit in the row number.

```
> myNewDf
  r1s1 r1s2 r2s1 r2s2 r3s1 r3s2 r4s1 r4s2 r5s1 r5s2
1    0    1    2    3    4    5    6    7    8    9
```

I suspect this is really simple and probably involves some combination of `reshape()`, `melt()`, and/or `cast()`, but the proper incantations are escaping me. I could post what I've tried, but I think it would just distract from what's probably a simple question? If anyone would like me to do so, just ask in the comments.

The ideal solution would also somehow programmatically generate the new column names based on the original data frame's column names, since the column names won't always be the same. Also, if it's not difficult, can I somehow simultaneously do this same operation to a list of similar data frames (all the same number of rows, all the same column names, but with differing values in their s1 & s2 columns)? Ultimately I need a single data frame that contains the data from multiple simpler data frames, like this...

```
> myCombinedNewDf # data combined from 4 separate original data frames
  r1s1 r1s2 r2s1 r2s2 r3s1 r3s2 r4s1 r4s2 r5s1 r5s2
1    0    1    2    3    4    5    6    7    8    9
2   10   11   12   13   14   15   16   17   18   19
3   20   21   22   23   24   25   26   27   28   29
4   30   31   32   33   34   35   36   37   38   39
```

Comment: is the pattern always `c(df[1, 2:3], df[2, 2:3], df[3, 2:3])` etc?

Comment: @rawr - I'm not sure what you mean; if you're talking about the values in the s1 & s2 columns, the actual data follows no pattern; the actual data is 'double' (floating-point) values from sensor readings.

Comment: I feel like your last bit should be a separate question.

Comment: @phonetagger I was saying that you only seem to be concatenating columns s1 and s2 by row which doesn't require any "reshaping" `c(t(myDf[, 2:3]))`

Comment: @rawr Sorry, yes, that is always the pattern I want. But the end result needs to be a data frame with named columns suitable for training/predicting with kernlab's `ksvm`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

base R solution

```
#prepare data
myDf1 = data.frame(Seconds=seq(0,1,.25), s1=seq(0,8,2), s2=seq(1,9,2))
myDf2 = data.frame(Seconds=seq(0,1,.25), s1=seq(10,18,2), s2=seq(11,19,2))

myDfList=list(myDf1,myDf2)

#allocate memory
myCombinedNewDf=data.frame(matrix(NA_integer_,nrow=length(myDfList),ncol=(ncol(myDf1)-1)*nrow(myDf1)))

#reformat
for (idx in 1:length(myDfList))  myCombinedNewDf[idx,]=c(t(myDfList[[idx]][,-1]))

#set colnames
colnames(myCombinedNewDf)=paste0("r",sort(rep.int(1:nrow(myDf1),2)),colnames(myDf1)[-1])
```

---

As per request an extended version that handles a separate factor column:

```
#allocate memory
#the first column should ultimately be a factor
#I would use a character column first and later change it to type factor
#note the stringsAsFactors option!
myCombinedNewDf=data.frame(rep(NA_character_,length(myDfList)),
                       matrix(NA_integer_,
                              nrow=length(myDfList),
                              ncol=(ncol(myDf1)-1)*nrow(myDf1)),
                       stringsAsFactors=FALSE)

#reformat
for (idx in 1:length(myDfList))  {
  myCombinedNewDf[idx,-1]=c(t(myDfList[[idx]][,-1]))
  #I have just made up some criterion to get one "yes" and one "no"
  #"yes" if the sum of all values is below 100, "no" otherwise
  myCombinedNewDf[idx,1]=if (sum(myDfList[[idx]][,-1])<100) "yes" else "no"
}

#set colnames
colnames(myCombinedNewDf)=c("flag",
                        paste0("r",
                               sort(rep.int(1:nrow(myDf1),2)),
                               colnames(myDf1)[-1])
                        )
myCombinedNewDf$flag=factor(myCombinedNewDf$flag)
myCombinedNewDf
```

Comment: I think I'm liking your solution best as it seems the easiest to understand, but I have some questions: Trying to walk through this bit by bit, I tried doing the right-hand side of `myCombinedNewDf[idx,]=c(t(myDfList[[idx]][,-1]))` assigned to a fresh variable, and I get a numeric vector of course, but if I do `newVar = data.frame(c(t(myDfList[[idx]][,-1])))`, the result is a data frame with 10 rows and 1 column, not a data frame with 1 row and 10 columns. Is there a way to force that data frame to be horizontal instead of vertical? I'm asking because I also need to insert a "yes"/"no" value.

Comment: Also, I think your solution is the only one that preallocates memory. What would I need to do differently to preallocate space for `myCombinedNewDf` if it also has an additional "yes"/"no" factor column as column #1? (Factor, not string)

Comment: As per your first request: You could wrap another transpose around `c(t(myDfList[[idx]][,-1]))` to get a column vector. Then, `data.frame(t(c(...)))` gives a single-row data.frame.

Comment: Ah, I understand. The problem is that the `c` operation then coerces the data into a common type. I am busy right now - will think about it later.

Comment: I have added some changes in order to incorporate the additional factor column. Is this what you wanted?

Answer (score 3):

Using `melt()` from `reshape2`, you can do it like this:

```
library(reshape2)

# Melt the data, omitting `Seconds`
df.melted <- melt(myDF[, -1], id.vars = NULL)

# Transpose the values into a single row
myNewDF <- t(df.melted[, 2])

# Assign new variable names
colnames(myNewDF) <- paste0("r", rownames(myDF), df.melted[, 1])

#   r1s1 r2s1 r3s1 r4s1 r5s1 r1s2 r2s2 r3s2 r4s2 r5s2
# 1    0    2    4    6    8    1    3    5    7    9
```

This melts the data frame, uses the first column (the variable names from the original dataset) to construct the variable names for the new dataset, and uses the transpose of the second column (the data values) as the row of data.

If you want an automated approach to combining your datasets, you can take this a step further:

```
# Another data frame
myOtherDF <- data.frame(Seconds = seq(0, 1, 0.25),
                        s1 = seq(1, 9, 2),
                        s2 = seq(0, 8, 2))

# Turn the above steps into a function
colToRow <- function(x) {
    melted <- melt(x[, -1], id.vars = NULL)
    row <- t(melted[, 2])
    colnames(row) <- paste0("r", rownames(x), melted[, 1])
    row
}

# Create a list of the data frames to process
myDFList <- list(myDF, myOtherDF)

# Apply our function to each data frame in the list and append
myNewDF <- data.frame(do.call(rbind, lapply(myDFList, colToRow)))

#   r1s1 r2s1 r3s1 r4s1 r5s1 r1s2 r2s2 r3s2 r4s2 r5s2
# 1    0    2    4    6    8    1    3    5    7    9
# 2    1    3    5    7    9    0    2    4    6    8
```

Answer (score 3):

The relevant values can be extracted row-wise by using `c(t(therelevantdata))`.

In other words:

```
Values <- c(t(myDf[-1]))
```

If names are important at this point, you can do:

```
Names <- sprintf("r%ss%s", rep(1:5, each = 2), 1:2)
```

You can get a named vector with:

```
setNames(Values, Names)
# r1s1 r1s2 r2s1 r2s2 r3s1 r3s2 r4s1 r4s2 r5s1 r5s2 
#    0    1    2    3    4    5    6    7    8    9
```

Or a named single-row `data.frame` with:

```
setNames(data.frame(t(Values)), Names)
#   r1s1 r1s2 r2s1 r2s2 r3s1 r3s2 r4s1 r4s2 r5s1 r5s2
# 1    0    1    2    3    4    5    6    7    8    9
```

---

If you have a `list` of your `data.frame`s, as shared in @cyro111's answer, you can easily do the following:

```
do.call(rbind, lapply(myDfList, function(x) c(t(x[-1]))))
#      [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4] [,5] [,6] [,7] [,8] [,9] [,10]
# [1,]    0    1    2    3    4    5    6    7    8     9
# [2,]   10   11   12   13   14   15   16   17   18    19
```

Convert to `data.frame` with `as.data.frame` and add the names with either `names <-` or `setNames`.

---

Generalized as a function:

```
myFun <- function(indf, asVec = TRUE) {
  values <- c(t(indf[-1]))
  Names <- sprintf("r%ss%s", rep(1:nrow(indf), each = ncol(indf[-1])),
                   1:ncol(indf[-1]))
  out <- setNames(values, Names)
  if (isTRUE(asVec)) out
  else (as.data.frame(as.matrix(t(out))))
}
```

Try it out:

```
myFun(myDf)        # Vector
myFun(myDf, FALSE) # data.frame
```

It's even more convenient on a `list` of `data.frame`s.... lots of options :-)

```
dfList1 <- list(
  data.frame(s = 1:2, a1 = 1:2, a2 = 3:4, a3 = 5:6),
  data.frame(s = 1:2, a1 = 11:12, a2 = 31:32, a3 = 51:52)
)

lapply(dfList1, myFun)
do.call(rbind, lapply(dfList1, myFun))
t(sapply(dfList1, myFun))
as.data.frame(do.call(rbind, lapply(dfList1, myFun)))
```

Comment: The OP thinks names won't always follow a pattern, so `Names <- paste0("r", rep(1:5, each = 2), names(myDf[,2:3]))` covers that case.

Comment: @Frank, if that were the case, then how do they plan to combine the different datasets later on?

Comment: I think he said that the data values, i.e. `0,1,2,3,...` in his case, do not follow a pattern. The names `s1` and `s2` are always the same I assume.

Comment: @cryo111, how can they not follow a pattern if they are being unlisted by row? I assume each row of a `data.frame` to contain the same number of elements unless there are `NA` or blanks.

Comment: Ah, I read "since the column names won't always be the same" as meaning they differ from one use case to another, not df to df in this hypothetical list.

Comment: @Frank - Sorry, didn't see this until now....  For any group of data frames being combined into one larger data frame, the column names will be the same. But I will be doing about 11 of these operations every 20 seconds or so (taking groups of related data frames & combining like data frames into larger data frames that are aggregates of the smaller frames). Within each of the groups, the column names are the same, but from one group to another they differ. It would be nice to have a single function or block of code that generically handles them all.

Comment: @cryo111 - I added a comment above.

Comment: @phonetagger, I've added a function that makes the approach easy to generalize. The function assumes we always drop the first column but that all other columns remain as valid data.

Answer (score 2):

You can try `dcast` from the devel version of `data.table` i.e. v1.9.5 which can take multiple `value.var` columns.  Create two columns one with `row number` ('rn') and the second a grouping variable ('grp'), and use `dcast`.  The installation details are [`here`](https://github.com/Rdatatable/data.table/wiki/Installation)

```
library(data.table)#v1.9.5+
dcast(setDT(myDf[-1])[, c('rn1', 'grp') := list(paste0('r', 1:.N), 1)],
                   grp~rn1, value.var=c('s1', 's2'))
#   grp r1_s1 r2_s1 r3_s1 r4_s1 r5_s1 r1_s2 r2_s2 r3_s2 r4_s2 r5_s2
#1:   1     0     2     4     6     8     1     3     5     7     9
```

Or we can use `reshape` from `base R`

```
 reshape(transform(myDf, rn1=paste0('r', 1:nrow(myDf)), grp=1)[-1], 
         idvar='grp', timevar='rn1', direction='wide')
 #  grp s1.r1 s2.r1 s1.r2 s2.r2 s1.r3 s2.r3 s1.r4 s2.r4 s1.r5 s2.r5
 #1   1     0     1     2     3     4     5     6     7     8     9
```

#### Update

If we have several dataframes, we can place the datasets in a list and then use `lapply` with `dcast` or rbind the datasets in the list with `rbindlist` specifying a grouping variable for each dataset,then apply `dcast` on the whole dataset.

Using 'myOtherDF` from @Alex A.'s post

```
 myDFList <- list(myDf, myOtherDF)
 dcast(rbindlist(Map(cbind, myDFList, gr=seq_along(myDFList)))[,-1,
       with=FALSE][, rn1:= paste0('r', 1:.N), by=gr],
          gr~rn1, value.var=c('s1', 's2'))
 #   gr r1_s1 r2_s1 r3_s1 r4_s1 r5_s1 r1_s2 r2_s2 r3_s2 r4_s2 r5_s2
 #1:  1     0     2     4     6     8     1     3     5     7     9
 #2:  2     1     3     5     7     9     0     2     4     6     8
```

Comment: When I do `install.packages("data.table")` and then `library(data.table)`, it tells me it's version `data.table 1.9.4`, and it also says it can't find function "dcast" (probably because it's not version 1.9.5?). How do I get version 1.9.5? .... ahh... the development version.

Comment: @phonetagger The details are https://github.com/Rdatatable/data.table/wiki/Installation

Comment: @phonetagger I added a base R option in case if there is difficulty in installing the devel version